# How can I launch a local VBScript with arguments from a C# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, console

I have a C# console application built with the latest .NET framework.

How can I launch/start a local .vbs file with arguments (example) from within the app:

```
"C:/my folder/import.vbs" agr1 agr2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    @"C:\my folder\import.vbs",
    String.Format("{0} {1}", agr1, agr2));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\my folder\import.vbs";
        start.Arguments = "agr1 agr2";
        process.StartInfo = start;
        process.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cscript.exe to launch it if you do not want pop-ups displayed, otherwise you can use wscript:

```
cscript import.vbs agr1 agr2
```

You can do this from C# by using the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start and ProcessStartInfo objects:

```
var si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo() { WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\", Arguments = "import.vbs arg1 arg2", FileName="cscript.exe" };
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(si);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

You could also start the import.vbs directly and Windows will use the default script host to execute it.  Simply adjust this line as follows:

```
var si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo() { WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\", Arguments = "arg1 arg2", FileName="import.vbs" };
```

The default scripting engine is wscript, which means that if your script has pop-ups, they will be displayed and will cause the script halt awaiting user confirmation/interaction.

If you launch it via cscript then any pop-up generated by the script will be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I have used it for scripts in the past.