# .vbs script is getting opened in notepad during execution

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am using C# as programming language and trying to execute .vbs script to clear temp cache before any automated test case execution.

I am facing one issue while execution.

When I execute .vbs file, it is getting opened in Notepad.

I am using standard Process and ProcessStartInfo class.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could convert the VB code into C#. Or you could call `wscript` with the argument being your vbs file, instead of directly running the file.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477120/how-can-i-launch-a-local-vbscript-with-arguments-from-a-c-sharp-console-applicat . It seems that default handler for VBS files is changed/altered to prevent direct execution, use wscript.exe with VBS file as command argument instead.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical (ie non console)

```
wscript c:\folder\file.vbs
```

.
Console

```
cscript //nologo c:\folder.file.vbs
```

You can clear from command prompt direct

```
echo Clear Temporary Internet Files: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8 


echo Clear Cookies: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 


echo Clear History: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1 


echo Clear Form Data: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16 


echo Clear Saved Passwords: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32 


echo Delete All: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255 


echo Delete All w/Clear Add-ons Settings: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
```